# Preventing multiple of the same Low Quality review comments

Tags: bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I came across this when reviewing low quality posts:

[image: Image of question with three comments that are exactly the same]

Three "This link may answer the question..." comments in a row, posted from the Low Quality review queue's comment dialog that appears when you recommend deletion.

This seems a little redundant; posting the same comment three times just makes it more noisy. It's fairly easy for reviewers to avoid doing this (just select the "No comment necessary" option), but that doesn't help if another reviewer posts the same comment in between you viewing the post and posting your own comment.

Can SO accept only the first of each of the Low Quality review comments?

Comment: [Related bug on the über-meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188843/low-quality-posts-reviews-add-comments-more-than-once-on-behalf-of-reviewer).

Comment: seems more like a bug than a feature-request to me

Comment: Yeah, a bug in the reviewer's intelligence.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi that bug is for a single person flagging repeatedly.  IMO not the same thing.

Comment: Seriously, I did always think that for example the "This is a link-only answer (and not spam)" would be treated differently, than any other option would be. Basically because this text implies that the answer is still useful, even if not perfect.

Comment: @BoltClock It's true that this is solved by reading, but think about how flags are treated versus this. When you flag you are expected to select a reason. People who then become reviewers make the same assumption here. You recommend deletion _then select a reason_

Comment: @BoltClock Even in the situation that "another reviewer posts the same comment in between you viewing the post and posting your own comment"?

Comment: @Shoe: Are you required to select a reason? I can delete posts without leaving a comment even from the review queue, but I'm not sure if that's just because I'm a moderator.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes the flag dialog doesn't let you continue until you select one of the radios.

Comment: @Shoe The very first option should be "no comment needed". Can you post a screenshot of what you see instead?

Comment: @Tavian Barnes: Oh, I missed that. Yeah the OP has a point there.

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes the review dialogs work fine, what I'm trying to say is that people don't realize that you can select "No comment needed" because they are used to the flag dialog which makes you select a reason.

Comment: @Shoe Ahh, I see your point.

Comment: In like with what @Shoe said, I always assumed that "No comment needed" was only for things that were so blatantly wrong giving an explanation was unneeded.

Comment: It's already supposed to work this way - it was designed with this functionality from day one. Retagging as a bug. Ref: HasExistingDeleteReasonId()

Comment: @BoltClock: no, it is a bug in the s*** system's intelligence; not to mention, even if you are Mr. Intelligence, it is entirely possible to hit the same reason twice by two people simultaneously while reviewing.

Comment: Saw this again today: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26532600/610573

Answer (score 48):

Instead of rejecting or ignoring the repeated "This sucks but I can't vote to close" comments from reviewers, I'd suggest treating repeats as up votes on the first one.

We still should have a way for to show that multiple reviewers thought something was garbage, and converting duplicate comments into upvotes has the benefit of not forcing reviewers to change their work flow.

Comment: I already do this manually
, but it would be great if the system did it for us.

Comment: This is exactly what happens with close votes - when you choose a custom reason that was given by another user, the system upvotes their comment on your behalf. I'm sure the same could be implemented with review comments.

Comment: Sort-of, but semi-yeah. Answers with multiple link-only comments will be very likely removed anyhow.

Comment: I already assumed that selecting the same reason as a previous reviewer up votes the existing comment.