# Common Delete Reason in VLQ Queue

Tags: support

Say I see a link only answer, so I hit "request deletion," then select the "link only" deletion reason.  This will autogenerate the comment:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

What if someone has already done this and the comment is posted?  Will there be a second identical comment from me or will it auto-upvote the existing comment?

Comment: From what I can see, neither action (no duplicate comment or upvote). Though I thought in the past the system would upvote the comment for you.

Comment: Seems like we all need to head to the VLQ queue for some testing

Comment: Found a related post. Not sure if this is the one I was thinking of: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265249/preventing-multiple-of-the-same-low-quality-review-comments and [Shog mentions it's supposed to not post duplicates](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265249/preventing-multiple-of-the-same-low-quality-review-comments#comment59331_265249) in the comments there, but I'm not sure if that was ever fixed.

Comment: @gunr2171, that was my first thought, but I figured I should check if someone already know before I went gallivanting around the VLQ queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will do neither. It won't post a new comment, and it also won't upvote the other comment.