# Review response already performed in Low Quality Post queue

Tags: discussion

I have a question about the Low Quality Posts Review Queue, similar to this question [Preventing multiple of the same Low Quality review comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265249/preventing-multiple-of-the-same-low-quality-review-comments), but not quite the same.

I am curious about the effect of voting "Looks OK" on a post which really needs improvement, but where someone has already left a comment to that effect.

My concern is the following: when I come across, for example, a LQP that is a "code only" answer, I typically leave a comment to the effect of "add explanation please" (assuming I don't grok the code).  And then I click "Looks Ok", because according to the [guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029) that's what you should do if the answer is not bad enough to delete.  In many cases, someone has already left this comment, so there is no reason for me to do it.  In that case, I click "Looks Ok" and move on.  I have read that users are sometimes audited for their review performance (and possibly banned temporarily), and I assume that it looks bad to click "Looks Ok" on a low quality answer that needs improvement, without even leaving a comment.  So does this behavior "harm" someone's review reputation in some way?  Should I just "skip" the review instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume that it looks bad to click "Looks Ok" on a low quality answer that needs improvement, without even leaving a comment

That is a false assumption.  The purpose of that queue is to delete posts that are so bad they shouldn't even be allowed to stay on the site.  If you see a post that meets the minimum standards for being an answer, and as such doesn't merit deletion, the only action that you need to take is to mark it as "looks okay".  Any further action that you choose to take is entirely optional.  If you want to comment on how the author can improve his post, downvote it, edit it to fix some problems you see with it, etc. you're more than welcome to, but you're not *obligated* to.  (This is different from first/last posts, where you should be doing everything you can to help the post and its author before moving on, and should only choose "no action necessary" if there's literally no possible action you can take to make the post better.)