# When reviewing LQP with a comment used previously, upvote the comment automatically

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

When we recommend deletion in a LQP review, we may use one of the pre-defined comments like

> **This is a “thank you” comment**
>   “Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.”

This is no rare case when one reviewer has already put such a comment and if we choose the same one, it is not written again which is somewhat understandable. I have a habit, however, to upvote such comments to indicate that more than one (reviewer) sees the same issue about the "answer". Why not automate this to avoid extra clicks? (not only skip adding a duplicate comment but also upvote the comment that would have been duplicated)

A bit more arguable but more useful scenario is – once I upvote a standart comment, clicking the "Recommended Deletion" button brings me to the next post at once without suggesting to pick a comment. This is not only 2 clicks less but also 1 scroll less, since even with 100% zoom (I have 120% by default) I see this:

[image]

This may be regarded as an issue of layout instead though.

Comment: I usually use "No comment" needed when I see someone else has already inserted the comment. You can upvote the comment yourself, if you feel it's important?

Comment: Doesn't selecting the same deletion comment automaticly upvote the one already posted?

Comment: @AndréKool no, I've checked that before posting

Comment: @AndréKool Flagging a question as a duplicate up votes the existing comment if you pick the same question as the dupe target, is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: @BSMP No I was thinking of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265249/preventing-multiple-of-the-same-low-quality-review-comments/265272#comment59331_265249). It is supposed to upvote the already posted comment. But i have also seen users post those comments outside of reviews (note the from review at the end of the comment). Unfortunatly i cant check it myself right now because im enjoying a little review ban.

Comment: I think im really starting to confuse myself (and maybe others) and should go to bed

Comment: There is one of the interfaces (close vote maybe?) that already does it